# How to use FCM to get real-time change from database server?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, oracle12c

I am fairly new to Flutter App development. Using online tutorials i have developed an HRMS app for our organisation. In that i need to implement **real-time push notifications** as well. The scenario is like this - we have an Oracle SQL database server(12c), tomcat app server (API's are deployed here) and Apache server for routing requests to app server. All 3 are different servers having different IP addresses.

**What needs to be accomplished**:-
If any specific changes are happening in my database, then i need to post that change in the form of notification in my flutter app. For e.g: if the leave of a person gets approved, that change should come to the app in the form of a push notification.

**Things that i have tried**:-
I have read many articles and looked into many codes, but haven't implemented any in my app since most of them talks about push notification using firestore - which wouldn't serve my purpose as i already have a DB server.

**My Problem**:-
I don't know what to do or how to constantly monitor for specific changes in DB and notify the change to user in form of a notification. Notification should come to app even if app is closed. FCM is the solution most are mentioning but **i cannot understand how to use FCM to monitor changes in Oracle db or how to establish a connection between my db server and FCM**?

Any help on how this can be implemented would be very helpful, as the deadline for completion of the app is near.

Comment: I haven't implemented this but one approach can be; instead of monitoring the DB, have a Java/any other server app which does the changes in DB and at the same time sends updates to the HRMS flutter app.  Also there is mention of [server protocols](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choose) in the FCM docs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check that out ASAP.

Comment: So from what you said, i can use the java API  to send  push notification at the time DB writing is successful. I will look into how that can be implemented. Thank you again for giving an idea.